# How to read specific numbers out of a file

Tags: variables, lua

I want to write a Lua script which will save and load my vars back into my program. I searched a bit in the Internet for code examples and now i have this:

```
--SetUp vars
accept = 1
strenght = 5
hp = 2

--create file
local f = assert(io.open("quicksave", "w"))
f:write(accept, "\n")
f:write(strenght, "\n")
f:write(hp, "\n")
f:close()

--Set vars to 0(simulate restart of program)
accept = 0
strenght = 0
hp = 0
print("accept: "..accept.."   Strenght: "..strenght.."   HP: "..hp)

--load in the saved vars
local f = assert(io.open("quicksave", "r"))
accept = f:read("*line")
strenght = f:read("*line")
hp = f:read("*line")
f:close()
print("accept: "..accept.."   Strenght: "..strenght.."   HP: "..hp)
```

This works fine for me, but how can I read only specific values from the file? For example: what should I do if i want to read out only the second line of the file (the var for strength)?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read and discard the first line:

```
--load in the second saved var
local f = assert(io.open("quicksave", "r"))
f:read("*line")
strenght = f:read("*line")
```

Nevertheless, I suggest you save your data as a Lua script that can be loaded with `dofile`. Something like:

```
return {
  accept = 1,
  strenght = 5,
  hp = 2
}
```

Then you can load it into a local variable and read the fields you need:

```
local state = dofile("state.lua")
strenght = state.strenght
```

Comment: It will require a separate library to represent a lua table as a piece of lua code. With same efforts, it is better to use some cross-language formats like json http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules